how to add default checked rows in shadcn data table?
https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/data-table I use data table from shadcn on top of tanstack table. I have set logic where you can create or edit set of products. I'm getting all products and showing them with data table. User can add multiple products to set. Now, when editing an existing set I want to implement checked data logic that if this set has some products inside already show them as default checked in table (where we have all products). How can I make it?
"use client";

import {
  ColumnDef,
  flexRender,
  getCoreRowModel,
  getFilteredRowModel,
  useReactTable,
} from "@tanstack/react-table";
import {
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableHead,
  TableHeader,
  TableRow,
} from "@/components/ui/table";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

interface DataTableProps<TData, TValue> {
  columns: ColumnDef<TData, TValue>[];
  data: TData[];
  checkedData: TData[];
}

export function DataTable<TData, TValue>({
  columns,
  data,
  checkedData,
}: DataTableProps<TData, TValue>) {

  const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
  });
  

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="rounded-md border">
        <Table>
          <TableHeader>
            {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
              <TableRow key={headerGroup.id}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => {
                  return (
                    <TableHead key={header.id}>
                      {header.isPlaceholder
                        ? null
                        : flexRender(
                            header.column.columnDef.header,
                            header.getContext(),
                          )}
                    </TableHead>
                  );
                })}
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableHeader>
          <TableBody>
            {table.getRowModel().rows?.length ? (
              table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => (
                <TableRow
                  key={row.id}
                  data-state={row.getIsSelected() && "selected"}
                >
                  {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
                    <TableCell key={cell.id}>
                      {flexRender(
                        cell.column.columnDef.cell,
                        cell.getContext(),
                      )}
                    </TableCell>
                  ))}
                </TableRow>
              ))
            ) : (
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell
                  colSpan={columns.length}
                  className="h-24 text-center"
                >
                  No results.
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            )}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

